# DLL Dependencies - different on different systems?

Tags: c++, dll, dependencies

I created an application, with the mingw compiler in a WinXP system. It worked fine. I then tried to run it in an older WinXP box(this has been in the shelf for some 6 months). The application terminated with an exception --'*The application could not initialize (0xc0150002)*'.

Running depends.exe on the app shows two unavailable dlls(ieshims.dll and wer.dll) in the target. But, in the build system, the dependency tree is different and has lesser dlls than in the old winxp box. I have all the latest windows updates done on both the systems.

Why is it that the same application depends on different dlls on different systems?
How do i solve this problem?

Thanks,
sundar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I've had this problem, it was due to not installing [certain redistributables](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=32BC1BEE-A3F9-4C13-9C99-220B62A191EE&displaylang=en) on the target machine (you may need to look for a VS 2008 redistributable, or even .Net framework redistributable).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same updates (and SPs, hopefully) then why are you calling on 'old' XP? Also, this could be an issue with corrupt IE install on the target.